# Additivity of time complexity?

Tags: c, time, time-complexity

I'm currently working on a project for school in which I have a time complexity restriction. I'm still beginning to learn to program so apologies of this question is stupid.

Essentially, lets say I have a constraint that my program must satisfy the time complexity O(n^2 + mlogm), where n and m are some sizes of input. Does that mean that's the maximum time complexity any specific component of my program can run in? That is, if I have a ton of, say, O(n^2 + m) functions, but  the most complex function runs in O(n^2 + mlogm), will I still satisfy this time bound? For example, if my program runs the following functions in order

functionA

functionB

functionC

functionD

And functions A, B, C are all O(n^2 + m) or something less than the time complexity restraint, but the last function is O(n^2 + mlogm), will my program be within the time constraint? Would that not somehow be O(n^2 + m ^ n^2 + m ^ n^2 + m + n^2 + mlogm) for the overall complexity?

I'm still learning about time complexity, so any help for this would be much appreciated. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Would referring to this [time-complexity cheat-sheet](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/), or perhaps better yet, this [more general discussion about time-complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11032015/645128) help?

Comment: @ryyker Didn't see that general dicsussion, that is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're executing different functions in sequence, you just choose the *worst* complexity and that's the overall complexity.

For example, if `fnA` was `O(n)` and `fnB` was `O(nn!)`, then any effect of `fnA` would be totally *swamped* by `fnB`, assuming they're run sequentially (not nested).

In your case, the final of your functions meet the requirement and the first three are better, so the overall complexity is that of the final one.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @tmako please don't delete questions after receiving answers to them, that is disrespectful to paxdiablo, not to mention destructive behavior as far as the site is concerned.